# How to return list of files with same directory name?

Tags: bash, loops, sorting, find, glob

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── 15_10_29
│   ├── NAME
│   ├── NAME_2
│   ├── NAME_3
│   ├── NAME_4
│   └── NAME_5
├── 15_11_09
│   ├── NAME
│   ├── NAME_2
│   ├── NAME_3
│   └── NAME_4
└── 15_11_17
    ├── NAME
    ├── NAME_2
    ├── NAME_3
    └── NAME_4
```

Inside each of the NAME subdirectories is a file called atom.pdb. I would like to return a list of the atom.pdb files that have the same "NAME" directory name.

```
./15_10_29/NAME/atom.pdb
./15_11_09/NAME/atom.pdb
./15_11_17/NAME/atom.pdb

./15_10_29/NAME_2/atom.pdb
./15_11_09/NAME_2/atom.pdb
./15_11_17/NAME_2/atom.pdb
```

...and so on and so forth.

I cannot seem to conceptualize how to do this. I imagine I would want to use find but I am better with bash globbing and in this case the code would have to be quite long so I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.

**Edit:**

`find . -wholename '*atom.pdb' | sort -t / -k3,3` is returning the desired results:

```
./15_10_29/NAME/atom.pdb
./15_11_09/NAME/atom.pdb
./15_11_17/NAME/atom.pdb
./15_10_29/NAME_2/atom.pdb
./15_11_09/NAME_2/atom.pdb
./15_11_17/NAME_2/atom.pdb
./15_10_29/NAME_3/atom.pdb
./15_11_09/NAME_3/atom.pdb
./15_11_17/NAME_3/atom.pdb
./15_10_29/NAME_4/atom.pdb
./15_11_09/NAME_4/atom.pdb
./15_11_17/NAME_4/atom.pdb
./15_10_29/NAME_5/atom.pdb
```

But now I'm not sure how to parse these and break them up by "NAME" to store in an array or concatenated string variable.

**Edit 2:**
Here is what I came up with:

```
ARR=()
for i in /*/*/ ; do
    ARR+=($(basename ${i}))
done

while read i; do
    ARR2=(/*/${i}/atom.pdb)
    echo ${ARR2[@]}
done < <(echo ${ARR[@]} | tr " " "\n" | sort -u)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753869/5800081

Comment: Why not just `find . -name atom.pdb -print`?

Comment: I need to group the output by basename so I can feed it into another program in batches. It's the logic in finding the matching basenames that is eluding me. Using find prints all of the pdb files and sorts them by the date directories, not the basename.

Comment: Your basename is just `atom.pdb`, right?

Comment: Basename is "NAME", "NAME_2", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob

# to find all files named atom.pdb
echo **/atom.pdb

# to find all atom.pdb files under a parent dir 'NAME'
echo **/NAME/atom.pdb

# to print all atom.pdb files, grouped by the same parent
while read -r dir; do
  files=$(echo **/"$dir"/atom.pdb)
  echo "Processing files $files"
  # do the processing
done < <(ls **/atom.pdb | cut -f2 -d/ | sort -u) # ls makes sure each file is on a different line, unless echo
```

Gives this output:

```
Processing files 15_10_29/NAME/atom.pdb 15_11_09/NAME/atom.pdb 15_11_17/NAME/atom.pdb
Processing files 15_10_29/NAME_2/atom.pdb 15_11_09/NAME_2/atom.pdb 15_11_17/NAME_2/atom.pdb
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to match directories by "NAME" and then return them as groups of files so that they can be processed together.

Comment: The problem here is that "NAME" is variable. So I would first need to find all of the unique NAME-level directory names before I could call ls.

Comment: `find . -name 'atom.pdb' | sort -t / -k3,3` returns a directory agnostic sort that I am after but I can't seem to then group the filepath results by NAME to store into separate variable.

Comment: I just updated my answer so that it loops through all the directories.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like post processing the sort is a good way to go:

```
find . -wholename '*NAME*atom.pdb' | sort -t / -k3,3
```

And if you need the grouping:

```
find . -name 'atom.pdb' | sort -t / -k3,3 | 
    awk -F/ '$3 != last{print ""}{last=$3}1'
```

Comment: The first part of your command works great, I now have a sorted list by the NAME directory. But the awk command is just returning the same list with the entire path, it doesn't seem to be grouping the files. Ideally I would like to store a concatenated string of filenames into separate variable based on the NAME directory to feed into another program.

Comment: The awk is just intended to insert blank lines between groups.

Answer (score 0):

Well I went ahead and successfully solved this in a bash shell manner after all.

```
ARR=()
for i in /*/*/ ; do
    ARR+=($(basename ${i}))
done

while read i; do
    ARR2=(/*/${i}/atom.pdb)
    echo ${ARR2[@]}
done < <(echo ${ARR[@]} | tr " " "\n" | sort -u)
```

ARR holds an array of unique NAME values and ARR2 holds a globbed list of the matching filenames that have the same NAME value in their parent directory.

Please feel free to correct me if there is a more elegant way to handle this. It seems to work though.